# SSIS Dataflow Task buffer failed

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

***Hello I have a dataflow that keeps failing and getting these errors***

Error: A buffer failed while allocating 983008 bytes.

Error: The system reports 63 percent memory load. There are 34275872768 bytes of physical memory with 12618432512 bytes free. There are 4294836224 bytes of virtual memory with 31694848 bytes free. The paging file has 47093956608 bytes with 12779012096 bytes free.

[OLE DB Source [121]] Error: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0x8007000E.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on OLE DB Source returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

***can anyone help me with this?***

Comment: Are you sure you're not using the 32-bit SSIS runtime? See [this DBA StackExchange answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/133779) for some clues.

Comment: Yes it is using 64 runtime